# How do we can save the effect of last action in React.js and Fabric.js

Tags: reactjs, fabricjs

These are states

```
     const {activeCanvas, activeObject} = useContext(CanvasStore)
     const [strokeWidth,setStrokeWidth]=useState(0)
     const [color,setColor]=useState("black")
     const [colorValue,setColorValue] =useState("white")
```

UseEffect() hook

```
    useEffect(()=>{
    if(activeObject?.subType === "Image"){
        setStrokeWidth(activeObject.strokeWidth)
        setColor(activeObject.color)
        setColorValue(activeObject.color)
    }

},[])
```

These are the functions, of those I want to maintain the result before next occurrence without rendering

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the issue that I faced is related to the condition (if) in useEffect hook. So, while writing that name it properly. Don't make hurry but look carefully the name of the field in object

```
     useEffect(()=>{
    if(activeObject?.custom.subType === "Image"){
        setStrokeWidth(activeObject.strokeWidth)
        setColor(activeObject.color)
        setColorValue(activeObject.stroke)
    }

},[])

    const borderColor=(color)=>{
    setColorValue(color)
    console.log(activeObject)
    if(activeObject?.custom.subType === "Image"){
        activeObject.set({stroke:color});
        activeCanvas.renderAll();
    }
}
```